# Is it worth it to use the reselect library and make selectors for each item in my store even if all I am doing is accessing items from the store

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I am in a situation where my store looks something like this

```
{
  itemA: {val1, val2, val3},
  itemB: {val1, val2, val3},
  ....
}
```

in my selector file I have something like this

```
const getItemAobject(state) => return state.itemA;
const getItemBobject(state) => return state.itemB;
```

....

```
const selectItemA = createSelector([getItemAobject], (itemAobject) => itemAobject);
const selectItemB = createSelector([getItemBobject], (itemBobject) => itemBobject);
```

finally in mapStateToProps I have

```
mapStateToProps(){
 {
  itemA: selectItemA(state)
  itemB: selectItemB(state)
 }
}
```

In this scenario where my selectors aren't doing anything fancy should I use reselect? I could have just as easily done this

```
mapStateToProps(){
 {
   itemA: state.itemA
   itemB: state.itemB
 }
}
```

What would be the advantage to using selectors if any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that particular situation, there's not a real benefit for Reselect.  In fact, your example `selectItemAObject` selector isn't doing anything useful at all, because the "output selector" is just returning the value it's given.

Overall, the main reasons for using selectors are:

- Encapsulate state lookups so the rest of the codebase doesn't need to know exactly where a given piece of data lives in the state tree
- Keep complex transformation logic in one place
- Improve performance by memoizing lookups and transformations, especially if they're expensive.

For more info, see my post [Idiomatic Redux: Using Reselect Selectors for Encapsulation and Performance](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/idiomatic-redux-using-reselect-selectors/).

Comment: Is it wrong to make reselect for every selector needed for memory usage?